# Css transforms not working unless I add a console.log

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The following snippet of code is supposed to create two elements (`frontEl` and `backEl`) inside another element (`rotatingEl`). `rotatingEl` is then supposed to attach to another element `el`. When this happens, I want it to do the css transform. However, it only does it when I put a `console.log(rotatingEl)` anywhere after it's created. I think it's a timing issue, but don't know how to solve it.

CSS:

```
.flip {
 transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

javascript

```
var frontEl = document.createElement("span");
frontEl.className = 'front';
frontEl.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;

var backEl = document.createElement("span");
backEl.className = 'back';
backEl.innerHTML = array[index + 1];

var rotatingEl = document.createElement("div");
rotatingEl.className = 'rotating flip';

rotatingEl.appendChild(frontEl);
rotatingEl.appendChild(backEl);

el.innerHTML = "";
el.appendChild(rotatingEl);

console.log(rotatingEl); // if I remove this, it breaks

rotatingEl.setAttribute("style", 
"-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);-moz-transform:  rotateY(-180deg);-o-transform:  rotateY(-180deg);transform:  rotateY(-180deg)");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're right about the timing issue, a hack would be adding a window.setTimeout.

Comment: You could use an interval and keep checking if the rotation is already done. After it is done, you could clear it.

Comment: In your case I think you must check when rotatingEl has his children correctly. Have you tried to use rotatingEl.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotateY(-180deg);', etc?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using `.style` with the same result. I think I need to check when `el.appendChild(rotatingEl)` is done, but am unsure how to delay adding className `flip` without using callbacks.